# MATLAB without using loops, determine if the variance is above the threshold, returning a 1 or 0

Tags: arrays, matlab, variance

I'm trying to write this program in MATLAB where, without using loops I need to take an array which has 3 rows, and an unknown number of columns.

We take this array, and find the variance of each of the columns. If that variance is grater than a threshold, then we set a the corresponding column in our output array to 1.

This is what I have so far:

```
% vec_acc_total is my array with 3 rows

var = var(vec_acc_total, 0, 1);

walking_segments_no_loops = zeros(size(var));
walking_segemnts_no_loops(var >= THRESHOLD) = 1
```

However something is wrong with this, hoping for any help, will be appreciated. I know it is wrong as after it is returned, It is put through a verification program (provided to me) which will confirm or deny.

There is also potentially an issue with my use of the VARIANCE function in MATLAB. I need to find the variance of each column.

I have tried the following:

```
walking_segments_no_loops = var >= THRESHOLD
```

Which also did not return the correct value

Answer (score 6):

When you run

```
var = var(vec_acc_total, 0, 1);
```

You are overwriting the built-in function `var` with your variable `var`. All subsequent calls to `var()` (the function) will error until you clear `var` (the variable) from your workspace.

So run `clear` to clean things up and prevent any shadowing, then pick a new variable name, e.g.

```
v = var(vec_acc_total, 0, 1);
```

`v` is a 1xN array, where `var_acc_total` was a 3xN matrix, which tells us intuitively that the variance for each column has been calculated.

You can directly check whether this exceeds a threshold without initialising an array:

```
walking_segments_no_loops = (v >= THRESHOLD);
```

This outputs a logical array the same size as `v`, which is `true (1)`  when greater than or equal to the threshold and `false (0)` otherwise. If you want this to be numerical instead of logical, you can convert it by wrapping with, for example, `double()`.

Note in your question you say this (emphasis mine):

> If that variance is **greater than** a threshold, then we set a the corresponding column in our output array to 1.

Maybe you want to use `>` instead of `>=` to check for a strict inequality.